# left join not showing null values

Tags: sql-server, null, left-join

I need to find the items that exist in table A but not in table B. Now that would be really simple in MySQL doing a join like this

```
select * from A 
left join B on A.key=B.key 
where B.key is null
```

However for some reason this is not working in MSSQL. I have created the query without the where clause to see all the results and I only see matches, not null values. Do you have any idea why this is not working?

I know I can alternatively use "when not exists" but I want to know the reason as to why with a join is not working.

I am adding the code for your review

```
select Absences.CustomerID, b.* 
from (
    select * from openquery(JUAN_INTERFACE,'select cmp_wwn from Planet_Customers where   i_outcome =4')) b 
left join Absences on Absences.CustomerID = b.cmp_wwn 
where Absences.Type = 3223
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause is filtering out null values:

```
where Absences.Type = 3223
```

You are left-joining from the `openquery` subquery to `Absences`; and then filtering only rows that have a specific (non-null) value in an `Absences` column.

Did you mean to join the other way around, from `Absenses` to `openquery`?

Comment: crap! you are right! my mistake. after seeing the same query so many times you loose the bolts!